# Camera Calibration of a Depth Camera

Tags: computer-vision

For a regular RGB camera, reading the wikipedia page for camera resectioning/calibration [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning), they divide the paramters into two categories:

Intrinsic: - focal length, scale factors in x and y, and principal point

Extrinsic: - the rigid body transform of the camera relative to some origin point

My question is how does camera calibration for a depth camera relate to these parameters, for example a Kinect v2 depth camera.

**Edit:** For example in the SUN RGB-D dataset, there are two files associated with each png image/ png depth image pair. An intrinsic file, and an extrinsic file.

The intrinsic file is a 3 by 3 matrix, example:

529.500000 0.000000 365.000000

0.000000 529.500000 265.000000

0.000000 0.000000 1.000000

From what I understand, using 1-indexing, entry (1,1) and (2,2) according to the [camera resectioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning) article on wikipedia are the focal length multiplied by scale factors relating "pixels to distance" (any elaboration on this appreciated). Whereas entries (1,3), (2,3) represent the coordinates of a principal point. Is this principal point in 2-D or 3D space and what do these numbers mean?

The extrinsics file/s (for some reason there are multiple files sometimes) are
a 4 by 4 matrix, example:

0.979445 0.201365 0.011827 0.000000

-0.201365 0.972640 0.115861 0.000000

0.011827 -0.115861 0.993195 0.000000

Which is a rigid body transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same.

The intrinsic calibration tells you the relationship between stuff "out there" *relative to the camera's frame of reference* and the image the camera makes.  The extrinsic calibration tells you how to get from the camera's frame of reference to whatever your "global" frame of reference may be.

Comment: I elaborated my question a bit to make it more specific. Thanks for the help.